# Log em VBScript

Tags: script, log, vbs

Preciso criar um log para ver quem utilizou meu script, e esse log tem que ir para um txt.

Segue abaixo o procedimento, como crio esse log que consta o user e a data

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim errorLevel

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")


VAR1 = InputBox ("Informe o nome da impressora", "Mapeamento de impressora", "Escreva o nome da impressora")

resp = MsgBox("Favor aguardar 5 minutos para finalizar o processo de mapeamento", vbokonly + vbInformationtisdesk, "Mapeamento de impressora")

WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\BRU02\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\CNO03\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\CPZ05\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\CTV02\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\CWBPS01BRF\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\EBU04\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\EBU16\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\HOR137\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\HORXPS01BRF\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\HORXPS02BRF\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\HORXPS03BRF\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\IAI03\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\IAI19\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\IAI22\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\MNE02\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\MRU03\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\NVM02\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\RVE06\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\RVE10\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\RVE11\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\SEC02\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\SPO37\"+VAR1,true
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\VDA16\"+VAR1,true


resp = MsgBox("    Por gentileza verificar se a impressora foi mapeada."& vbCrLf &"Caso nao tenha sido, favor entrar em contato com Help Desk de TI", vbokonly + vbInformationtisdesk, "Mapeamento de impressora")

WshShell.run("control printers")
```

No aguardo.

Comment: Não seria o caso de criar uma função 'log' e inserir dentro dessa função? Você quer um modelo de função para gerar um arquivo log em TXT, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo, preciso que quando o usuário acesse esse script ele edite o txt que fica no servidor publico e preencha o txt com id(user) e data